# Focus is set only once on button on Modal dialog using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, focus

I have a `button` on my webpage. If I click on that button, `Modal Dialog` is opened on which 2 buttons(`OK & Cancel`) are there. I want my web page to be operated without mouse. So when Modal Dialog is opened, automatically. The focus should be set on `OK` button. When dialog is closed, focus should be set on original button on web page. My code is as below. When I am clicking on `Open` button for the 1st time, focus is set on `OK` button. But when I am closing the modal and reopening it, it is not getting set on `OK` button.

```js
$scope.OpenModal = function() {
  //Popup the Modal Dialog Box
  $scope.modalTitle = "Confirm?";
  $scope.note=null;
  $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  
  $scope.focusInput=true;
  
  
  $scope.ok = function () {
   $scope.Message = "Confirmed";
   _clearSKUFormOnConfirm();
   $scope.modalShown = false;
   $scope.focusInput = true;
  }
  
  $scope.cancel = function () {
   $scope.Message = "Cancelled";
   _clearSKUFormOnCancle();
   $scope.modalShown = false;
   $scope.focusInput = true;
  }
 }

app.directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close close' ng-click='hideModal()'>x</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
  };
});

app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
   return {
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
       scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
         console.log('value=',value);
         
         if(value === true) { 
           $timeout(function() {
             element[0].focus(); 
           }, 20);
         }
       });
       element.bind('blur', function() {
         console.log('blur')
         scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
       })
     }
   };
});
```

```html
<button ng-click="OpenModal()" ng-disabled="isValid"
 role="button" >
<span class="fa fa-ban"></span> Open
</button>
<modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='440px'>
 <div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
     <p>{{modalMessage}} </p>
    </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button ng-click="ok()" focus-me="true" >OK</button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
 </div>
</modal-dialog>
```

Comment: I figured out that basically my directive "focusMe" is not getting called when popup is open 2nd time. But I couldn't find out the solution. Please suggest.